# State 'postgres.user_update' was not found in SLS

Tags: git, postgresql, github, salt-stack

Facing following error

```
"State 'postgres.user_update' was not found in SLS"
```

for the following sls file

```
postgres_user_update:
    postgres.user_update:
      - username : postgres
      - host : rhapsody-test4dde
      - port : 5432
      - password : 1235
```

Any leads ?

Comment: Your problem is hard to debug if you don't provide us with more information. How is configured your salt master (especially `file_roots` setting), where is this sls file, ...?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. I got it resolved. Apology for late response.

Answer (score 0):

`postgres.user_update` is an execution module function, not a state module function. I believe what you're looking for is `postgres_user.present`

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.postgres_user.html#module-salt.states.postgres_user

Documentation on the Postgres execution module: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.postgres.html#module-salt.modules.postgres

Comment: Thanks for redirecting to the pages.